# AWS Cloudformation+Beanstalk error Invalid YAML template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am using the **aws eb deploy** command on **ubuntu** to deploy a cloudformation script shown below. I get an error shown below.

Note: My other cloudformation scripts work without any problems.

> ***Error Invalid Yaml***: mapping values are not allowed here in "" 
>   CacheSecurityGroupName: Ref: "CacheSecurityGroup"
>   ^, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (R) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
>   **ERROR: Failed to deploy application.**

```
Resources:
  CacheSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroupIngress"
    Properties:
      CacheSecurityGroupName: Ref: "CacheSecurityGroup"
      EC2SecurityGroupName: Ref: "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
```

Looking for pointers to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use the full [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) function form in a new line, like this:

```
Resources:
  CacheSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroupIngress"
    Properties:
      CacheSecurityGroupName:
        Ref: "CacheSecurityGroup"
      EC2SecurityGroupName:
        Ref: "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
```

...or the short form, like this:

```
Resources:
  CacheSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroupIngress"
    Properties:
      CacheSecurityGroupName: !Ref "CacheSecurityGroup"
      EC2SecurityGroupName: !Ref "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
```